# Calling javascript from code behind not working as expected

Tags: asp.net

So I was making a page for creating accounts and saving them inside a database. To check if the code is working, I added debug messages between some lines of code using:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                "textas", "alert('test')", true);
```

The problem is that it turned out that having two debug messages will cause the page to not display any of them. I tested a simple code in an another page (shown below) and got the same problem. I also realized that showing one message will eventually make the code stop at where the debug message was, so any code that comes after won't run.

```
        protected void test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                "textas", "alert('test')", true);
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                "textasd", "alert('test1')", true);
        }
```

Am I missing something or is that some kind of bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding semicolons to the end of the js statements.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
    "textas", "alert('test');", true);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
    "textasd", "alert('test1');", true);
```

Comment: Oh my! How could I miss that!

Comment: It's a weird error that you'd think the browser would overlook, but no...